# How to manage lifetime scopes inside WCF services without using ILifetimeScope directly?

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac

Here's my simple WCF service which was integrated with [Autofac.Wcf](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html):

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IResponseBuilder _responseBuilder;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IOperation> _operations;

    public MyService(IResponseBuilder responseBuilder, IEnumerable<IOperation> operations)
    {
        _responseBuilder = responseBuilder;
        _operations = operations;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public object Execute()
    {
        foreach (var operation in _operations)
        {
            operation.Execute();
        }
        return _responseBuilder.Build();
    }
}
```

I want all operations to use the **same instance** of `IResponseBuilder` to build the result. Example of an operation:

```
public class AlwaysFailOperation : IOperation
{
    private readonly IOperationResultBuilder _resultBuilder;

    public AlwaysFailOperation(IOperationResultBuilder resultBuilder)
    {
        _resultBuilder = resultBuilder;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _resultBuilder.Fail();
    }
}
```

I know that it can be achieved with `ILifetimeScope` or `IContainer` inside `MyService`, but I want to keep all container work in composition root.

Please help me with this requirements. Here's my current registrations:

```
public static void AppInitialize()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<MyService>();
    builder.RegisterType<ResponseBuilder>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    builder.RegisterType<AlwaysFailOperation>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need the same instance of `IResponseBuilder` per request - i.e. `builder.RegisterType().InstancePerLifetimeScope()`. Or the same instance all the time - i.e. `builder.RegisterInstance(instance)`?

Comment: @ChimaOsuji I need the same instance of IResponseBuilder per request. `InstancePerLifetimeScope` will work. I didn't know that autofac wcf infrastructure creates a lifetime scope for each request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InstancePerLifetimeScope` should work, but you'll have to test it in your particular scenario.

Due to restrictions with the internals of WCF there is no per request lifetime in WCF. [See the bold comment at top of docs.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/wcf.html) WCF is very limiting with respect to its DI integration points.

Autofac creates an instance context for each instance of the service. That context contains a lifetime scope from which the service instance is resolved. The scope is not named because for singleton services the instance context lives for the life of the service - that's controlled by WCF, not Autofac.

So, hypothetically, **if you made your service instance per request in WCF and registered the dependency as instance per lifetime scope you should get the result you want**. But, as always, test, test, test. Sometimes getting the right WCF setup with the right Autofac lifetime registrations can be tricky, especially in a complex system.